# Arm template deployment fail with 409 error for one specific storage account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage

I use arm template to deploy a storage account. However, I got an error saying: StorageAccountAlreadyExists: The storage account named xxx already exists.

My release pipeline is set to incremental, so shouldn't really show this error.

I changed storage account name to a new one, not only it worked the first time, but I can keep on deploying the same pipeline and no error ever thrown out.

Looks like it is something specific to this account, however, I can't see anything special. The arm template we use is also quite normal (something we got from official examples before).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-06-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "StorageDescriptor": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "StorageAccount",
      "metadata": {}
    },
    "StorageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[toLower(concat(parameters('StorageDescriptor'), resourceGroup().name))]",
      "metadata": { "Description": "Override name for the storage account" }
    },
    "StorageType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_ZRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS",
        "Premium_LRS"
      ]
    },
    "Environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "PreProd",
      "metadata": { "description": "PreProd or Prod" }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('StorageAccountName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Web Job Storage Account"
        
      },
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "[parameters('StorageType')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your release pipeline is set to **incremental**, the storage account name must be unique every time you deploy. Refer to: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#naming-storage-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

> Arm template deployment fail with 409 error for one specific storage account

You need to check if the storage account attributes have been changed through the Azure/PowerShell portal by somebody else, and are different than the ones specified on the ARM template.

To resolve this issue, please try to export the template and update it in the Azure devops repo:

[image]

Then, we could update this new exported template file as you want and deploy with it.

As test, I could keep on deploying the same pipeline and no error ever thrown out.

[image]

Comment: hi, I exported the arm template, but can't see anything different

Comment: @daxu, Do you have the same storage account in other resource groups? You can verify it in different resource groups. I am limited to creating another resource group and cannot help you verify it.